# Alfresco drupal CMIS browser gives 404 error when tried to browse CMIS field

Tags: drupal, alfresco

I am using Drupal CMIS module for integrating Alfresco with Drupal

I get the following notice when I try to add CMIS field:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cmis_field_rootFolderPath in cmis_field_field_widget_form() 
(line 123 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7.22\sites\all\modules\cmis\cmis_field\cmis_field.module).
```

and when I click browse button it returns 404 error

I am using Drupal 7.22 and CMIS 7.x-1.3

The release note says the issue is fixed but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

well .. I fixed it by setting documentRoot to my drupal folder

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Can you show an example of your fix because I didn't understand clearly what you have done.